# Boto3 AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'tags'

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3

When I run my script I get the error: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'tags'`

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
instance_id_list = input("Enter an instance ID separated by commas: ")
instance_ids = instance_id_list.split(",")
print("Deleting Instance IDs:")
for instance_id in instance_ids:
    instance = ec2.describe_instances(
        InstanceIds=[instance_id]
    ) ['Reservations']

    #ec2info = defaultdict()
    #for tag in instance.tags:
    #    if 'Name'in tag['Key']:
    #         print(tag['Key'])
    #        name = tag['Value']
    # Add instance info to a dictionary    \
    print(instance.get('Instances'))
    ec2info[instance.id] = {
        'Name': instance.get('Reservations').get('Instances').get('InstanceId'),
        'Instance ID': instance.id,
        'Type': instance.instance_type,
        'State': instance.state['Name'],
        'Private IP': instance.private_ip_address,
        'Public IP': instance.public_ip_address,
        'Launch Time': instance.launch_time
        }


attributes = ['Name', 'Instance ID', 'Type',
              'State', 'Private IP', 'Public IP', 'Launch Time']
for instance_id, instance in ec2info.items():
    for key in attributes:
        print("{0}: {1}".format(key, instance[key]))
        #print(instance.terminate())
        print("------")
```

Here is the full output of my script:

```
        Enter an instance ID separated by commas: i-024d1b8e8eaa8e417,i-03804b280877175be
    Deleting Instance IDs:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File ".\aws_ec2_terminate_instances.py", line 13, in <module>
        for tag in instance.tags:

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'tags'
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Well, the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances) says that `describe_instances()` returns a dict, and dicts don't have a `tags` attribute. I'm not sure exactly what you meant to do there.

Comment: Boto 3 documentation states that `describe_instances` returns a dict, not an object, yet it seems that you are trying to access tags directly as if it was a field?

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances

Comment: Ok, what I'm trying to do is to print the Name tag from the instance (if it has one). I am learning python so I am becoming familiar with these terms. What I think I need to do is convert from a 'dict' to a text so that I can get at the Name tag. Is that correct?

Comment: I've edited the OP to include the entire script so that you can see what I am trying to print.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2 fixes needed

1) Append `[0]['Instances'][0]` to get the instance details

```
instance = ec2.describe_instances(
        InstanceIds=[instance_id]
    ) ['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]
```

2) `instance` is not an object, but just a regular dict containing a 'Tags' key.

```
>>> instance['Tags']
[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'instance-1'}]
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding the first line got me passed the error in the OP. But I am getting an error on this line: `instance['Tags'][{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': instance_id}]`. I changed 'instance-1' from your example to my instance_id variable. The error I get now is: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict`. What can I do about this error?

Comment: `instance['Tags']` is a interactive command to output its content.
Then the second line `[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'instance-1'}]` is just an output.